# PHP Mkdir not executing recursively?

Tags: php, mkdir

The following works in windows:

```
mkdir('../my/folder/somewhere/on/the/server', 0777, true);
```

I am talking about [PHP mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

It works perfectly, and creates the subfolders recursively. However, if I run the same command on a linux server, the folders aren't created.

Previously I solved this by breaking up the path and creating each folder one by one. But I don't want to do that because it should work with the "resurive" flag set to true. Why isn't it working?

Comment: It is useful to read the manual page - http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir

Comment: Works for me (inside php on linux).

Comment: What happens when you use an absolute path?

Comment: absolute path is not an option for me in this context.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there must be some problem apart from the `mkdir` command itself.

This tiny example works as expected and recursively creates the directories for me when executed on Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
mkdir ('testdir/testdir2/testdir3',0777,TRUE);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This are the thing have discovered

- Make sure the root path exists
- Make sure the root path is writable
- Don't use `..` always use real path ...

Example

```
$fixedRoot = __DIR__;
$recusivePath = 'my/folder/somewhere/on/the/server';

if (is_writable($fixedRoot) && is_dir($fixedRoot)) {
    mkdir($fixedRoot . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $recusivePath, 0, true);
} else {
    trigger_error("can write to that path");
}
```

Comment: Please add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors","On");` also `var_dump` i would like to see the output ....

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your PHP user (eg `www-data`) has permission to write to the parent folders of any folder it is trying to create. PHP needs to be able to write to the lowest one that already exists.

For example, in the case of `../my/folder/somewhere/on/the/server`, if `../my` already exists and PHP is able to write to `..` but not to `my`, `mkdir` will fail.

If your user is `www-data`, you could use `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ../my` to give write permission for `my` and all its subfolders.